# Java: Enums / constructors

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public class Item{
String name, color;
int weight, volume, cost;

public Item(String name, int weight, int volume, int cost, String color){
    this.name= name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.color = color;
}
```

I used this to create an ArrayList of items by loading in a csv file with the data. I have items in the array such as Apple, Pear, Noodles, etc. Currently to look at the items I have to call itemList.get(2). I'd love to be able to call itemList.APPLE or some variation so I don't have to always know that the index number associated with the item. Is there a way to do this? It seems like it would be an enum trick.

.

Next I have a class that is similar but I want to create an object x with:

> Item x = new Item(200, weight);
>
> x.toString()   ............... outputs: weight= 200, volume= 0, cost= 0, value= 0, base= 0, height= 0

from this code:

```
public class Item{
int weight, volume, cost, value,
base, height;

public Item(int x, String variable) {
    //some code 
}
```

in the code I would start by setting all the variables equal to 0, but then I need to use the string value to select which variable to add x to. How would I do this? I could use a big if, if else, if else statement adding x to the respective variable if the string.equals("__"), but I simplified the variables; there are actually about 30 of them. Do I just have to make a really long if statement or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are asking about creating `enum`s dynamically at runtime, the answer is no.

Comment: What's wrong with lots of setters?

Answer (score 0):

First, depending on the list abstraction you're using, you can specify where you're putting the values.  If instead you want to retrieve a particular object at any time, look into a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead:

```
Map<String, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
itemMap.put("apples", new Item("Apple", 1, 1, 1, "Red"));
itemMap.get("apples");  // gives you the item you placed in as an Apple
```

Of course, you'd want to [override `equals()` and `hashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) before doing that.  Furthermore, you won't be allowed to enter duplicate values to the mapping.

Next, the second *could* be done with reflection, but why not just use conventional setters and getters?

```
Item item = new Item(); // or whichever constructor you choose
item.setWeight(200); // sets weight to 200
System.out.println(item); // will print item as you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 30 variables with a Map, mapping each name to its value.